# passwordless sudo apachectl

Tags: mac, osx-lion, apache-http-server, sudo, sudoers

I'd like to be able to restart apache under OS X Lion without entering a password. I tried placing this in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
<User> ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

But when I execute `apachectl graceful` I get an error message:

```
This operation requires root.
```

What do I have to do, in order to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to `sudo`, otherwise you are executing the command as your user by default. The difference is that it doesn't require you to enter the password.

```
sudo apachectl graceful
```

Remember that, for changes in `visudo` to be applied, you need to quit the editor. It's not enough to save, since the changes are initially applied to a temporary file only.

---

You can always define an alias or function in your shell, like the following:

```
alias apachectl='sudo apachectl'
```

Store it in your personal shell configuration file (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`) to persist.